# bazaar remote host changed

Tags: repository, host, bazaar

A while ago, I set up a remote Bazaar repository and have been committing to and updating from it. The domain on which I set it up has been redirected to a load balancer due to some other configuration changes and I don't have a way to direct ssh traffic on that domain to the correct box.

Is there a way to change my local bazaar configuration to point to the correct IP address or another domain without starting over?

Edit: Solved my own problem...

This is accomplished through the bzr bind command. You can see your current remote brach by using:

```
bzr info
```

This will display something like:

```
Checkout (format: 2a)
Location:
       checkout root: .
  checkout of branch: sftp://[username]@[IP or HOSTNAME]/srv/bzr/trunk/
```

You can then set your remote branch like this:

```
bzr bind sftp://[username]@[IP or HOSTNAME]/srv/bzr/trunk/
```

You should now be able to update and commit.